# stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: does not work

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm trying to import a csv created by filemaker and copied onto my device using iTunes filesharing. I'm stuck on what should be a straightforward step. I just can't see where I'm going wrong. Tried the alternative method and setting UTF8 encoding. Also tried exporting from filemaker as xml UTF8, and also tried deleting the app from the phone and rerunning. It doesn't seem to read the encoding even if I specify it. The following code gives me this console output.

File exists
Import (null) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 264.)"

```
-(void)importDatabase {
NSString *importString;
NSError *error;
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/iPhone.csv"]]) {
    NSLog(@" File exists");
    NSStringEncoding encoding;
    importString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/iPhone.csv"] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"Import %@ %@ ",importString, error);
} else {
    NSLog(@" File doesn't exist");
}
```

}

Answer (score 7):

From the header:

```
NSFileReadUnknownStringEncodingError = 264,         // Read error (string encoding of file contents could not be determined)
```

Try telling Foundation what the encoding is, as you know what the encoding is.

```
importString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: blah encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
```

Comment: Yes. I think this is the problem. It doesn't know what the encoding is. In fact I was ignoring the 2 warnings below. It seems there are files missing from 4.2.1. I replaced them from 4.2 and it now magically works. There's are other posts suggesting this was an oversight by Apple.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out that the file was encoded in some strange code page (with >128 characters), instead of UTF-8. In the end, i never did figure out how it was encoded originally...

Answer (score -9):

I think you just forgot *[NSString alloc]* because this works for me:

```
NSString *fileComponents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```